# Transfer files from FTP server to local unix server

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I have to transfer files whose names consists of two variables X, Y and they are in the directory ABC in ftp server to my local unix directory XYZ. after transfering files i have to go to local directory path and I should untar (input files are compressed files) them. I have to use username and password for connecting to FTP. When copying files to local server also I have to use my username and password.

Here's my current attempt. Will it work? How can I improve it?

```
ftp -n hostname <<EOF
user username pwd
cd ABC
get ls *X*.tar | ls *Y*.tar username1@pwd1 : XYZ
EOF
bye
for next in `ls *.tar`
do
tar -zvxf $next
done
```

Comment: you can't work with scp while in ftp.

Comment: between <<EOF and EOF you can not use other commands than those of ftp, no scp, no cp. get is no command at all, it is wget, but that needs to be called instead of ftp command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code. Hope this helps you.

```
#! /bin/bash

cd local_path
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
file_name='files'

for HOST in ftpserver
do
echo $HOST
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
bin
prompt

cd "remote_path"
lcd "local_path"

mget $file_name.gz*

quit
END_SCRIPT
done

#extract file
mkdir -p ../archive/$DATE
for HOST in ftpserver
do
        gunzip $file_name.gz
done
```

Comment: but 
1. i have different usernames and pwds for local and ftp server.
2. i have to select files whose names should contain X and Y

Comment: you should investigate a little bit on yourself, if you have different usernames for ftp and ssh, just add another variable for it.

Comment: @musicking123: 1) You said you have diff user and pass for local and ftp. In my code you have to put ftp user and pass, no need for local user/pass. 2) You can use *X*.tar and *Y*.tar while mget.

Comment: Just to inform that ftp is running against $host if you are running this for more then one host. If you dont want, you can simply remove/comment this.

Comment: As I remember the golden rules of shell scripting no script should provide output while execution if not explicitly switched by user e.g. via -v switch. No good style to provide informative output on unix shells.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just look into the manual of [ftp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ftp) command line ftp-tool and script with that.

Alternative: use [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) to download the ftp-file to local machine, then scp to target machine, I suppose using public-key-authentication for ssh, that scp does not need a password, then it should end up simple like this.

```
wget --ftp-user=$USERNAME --ftp-password=$PASSWORD ftp://$HOSTNAME/ABC/$Y.tar
scp $Y.tar $SCPUSER@$SCPHOST/targetpath/$X.tar
```

Comment: well, i guess not, you try to send the ftp server your scp-command.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wget` to download files from FTP server to `unix` system

```
cd YOUR_DIRECTORY

wget --user=USERNAME --password='PASSWORD' HOST_NAME/REMOTE_PATH/FILE_NAME.EXTENSION
```