# How to import csv files from ftp server to hadoop(HDFS/HIVE/HBASE)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

My source files are located in ftp server in csv format. I want to import those files to HDFS for further processing. I am not aware about how to get those csv files.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I think this should help you: [copy files from ftp to hdfs][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627771/copy-files-from-ftp-to-hdfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a 2 step process and upload files to hdfs.

Step 1: Download the files from ftp server and store in local . This should help : [Transfer files from FTP server to local unix server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327916/transfer-files-from-ftp-server-to-local-unix-server)

Step 2: Once you have the files in local you can use hadoop fs -put to transfer the files to hdfs.

Example. if you file name is temp.csv you can do:

```
hadoop fs -put temp.csv $hadoop_path
```

Comment: Above solution works for small files but results in space issue for big files.. wht could be the elegant solution to ftp large files directly on hdfs.. looking for some suggestions